# Segue to Tab Bar Controller with performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, uistoryboard

I'm learning iOS and I'm working on what amounts to a Proof of Concept app in XCode 4.2.  I essentially want to allow a user to enter a user/pass combo and if the user is in an array of objects, pass them on to the "Content" view, but if not, pass them on to the "Register" view.

In either case, since the app itself will be a tabbed app (though the login and register views are not tabbed), I need to be able to segue from a typical ViewController to a TabViewController.

```
- (void)logIn:(id)sender{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Content" sender:sender];
```

}

Currently, I have the app segueing to the proper ViewController, which is a TabBarController embedded in a NavViewController...but once it gets there...there are no tabs!!

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you aren't loading TabBarController that's why you don't have any tabs.

What I suggest you:

In Log In ViewController you can also add "register" button, and place a segue from it to Register View Controller.

Add IBAction from log in button, which will check for log in and pass, and if it's OK load Content ViewController or TabBar Controller with Content ViewController.

I strongly recommend you to study iOS5 storyboard tutorials to get to know how the view controllers interacts.

Comment: Hmm, I've been studying them quite extensively, to be honest. What exactly do you mean when you say that I'm not loading TabBarConteoller?  Recently, I've been able to simply drop a TBController in the Storyboard and run it and the tabs show up. Why is this any different?

Comment: You don't have segue for TabBarController. And I suppose that you don't instantiated this controller programmatically

Comment: so, it turns out that my issue was that when i segue to the TabController, it was erroring out because I am trying to access a UILabel in the destinationViewcontroller in the TabBarViewController...but apparently, the prepareForSegue i'm not accessing the right tab in the new TabBarController.  I'm just not seeing very many examples out there of what i'm trying to do using the Storyboard.

Comment: You can access your Destination ViewController properties through KVC.

Comment: Flink, I ended up creating a model and storing objects there and making sure each VC has access to the data.  this seemed to work better than trying to pass data between the views.  I wish I understood your answer and comments, but as a previously declared "learner" of iOS programming, I don't.  Thanks for the time and help anyway.